# How to extract several entries (matching certain condition) from data frame and store them all in a new data frame, when entry itself is matrix

Tags: r, list, tidyr

I am writing a code in R to perform calculations using a set of input parameters. The calculations are done within a function, and the function returns different types of results together in one list.
I want to perform the calculations for all different combinations of input parameters. I use pmap to do so.
And now comes my problem: the function returns a list of results (e.g. a summed value, product value, and an arbitrary matrix) for every combination of parameters. I would like to be able to select, from the data frame containing all the output, all the 'summed values' for a certain condition (e.g. 'parameter 1 used), and store them together in a new data frame.

This last step is proving difficult; I can't manage to select all the summed values at once, just the first occurrence where the condition is met is selected.

Thank you in advance for any advice on the topic!

This is the example code I wrote:

```
library(tidyverse)
# parameter settings
bees1 <- seq(100, 200, 10)
bees2 <- seq(1000, 2000, 100)
a <- c( "A1" =1, "A2" = 2, "A3" =3)
b <- c( "B1" = list(bees1), "B2" = list(bees2))
c <- c( "C1" = 0.1, "C2" = 0.2, "C3" = 0.3)

# Creating a tibble containing parameters (in different formats) to be used in a function
# Using 'expand' to ensure all different combinations of parameters are subsequently used in function
params <- tibble(
  expand.grid(Aparam = a, Bparam = b, Cparam = c))

# function taking parameters as arguments and returning results of different dimensions:

fun <- function(ParamA, ParamB, ParamC){
  
  out_sumAC <- sum( ParamA, ParamC )
  out_productABC <- ParamA * ParamB * ParamC
  out_dataframe <- array( ParamA, dim = c(10, 10))
  
  return(list( SUM = out_sumAC, PRODUCT = out_productABC, DATAFRAME = out_dataframe))
  
}

# Applying function to dataframe of parameters 
params <- params |> mutate( out = pmap(list( Aparam, Bparam, Cparam), fun))

params_unnested <- params |>
  unnest(out)

# Extracting relevant data (in this case the data created with parametersettings A1) from the new dataframe
specific_results <- params_unnested[ params_unnested$Aparam == 1,"out"]

sum_results <- specific_results$out$SUM

# QUESTION: how would I extract in one go, from 'specific_results', not just the first SUM,
# but all SUM and store them in a new dataframe. AND, how would I do that for the results in form of matrixes
# (each entry in the new dataframe being itself a matrix... )
```

Answer (score 0):

`specific_results$out` is a list with repeated names, which is generally discouraged for exactly this kind of misbehavior. To get all elements named `"SUM"`, index with `names() == "SUM"`:

```r
specific_results[names(specific_results$out) == "SUM", "out"]

# # A tibble: 6 × 1
#   out         
#   <named list>
# 1 <dbl [1]>   
# 2 <dbl [1]>   
# 3 <dbl [1]>   
# 4 <dbl [1]>   
# 5 <dbl [1]>   
# 6 <dbl [1]>
```

To get a numeric column, use `unlist()`:

```r
sum_results <- specific_results[names(specific_results$out) == "SUM", "out"]
sum_results$out <- unlist(sum_results$out)
sum_results

# # A tibble: 6 × 1
#     out
#   <dbl>
# 1   1.1
# 2   1.1
# 3   1.2
# 4   1.2
# 5   1.3
# 6   1.3
```

Finally, note that if you use `unnest_longer()` instead of `unnest()`, it will add list names as a new column, which may be easier to work with:

```r
params |>
  unnest_longer(out)

# # A tibble: 54 × 5
#    Aparam Bparam       Cparam out             out_id   
#     <dbl> <named list>  <dbl> <named list>    <chr>    
#  1      1 <dbl [11]>      0.1 <dbl [1]>       SUM      
#  2      1 <dbl [11]>      0.1 <dbl [11]>      PRODUCT  
#  3      1 <dbl [11]>      0.1 <dbl [10 × 10]> DATAFRAME
#  4      2 <dbl [11]>      0.1 <dbl [1]>       SUM      
#  5      2 <dbl [11]>      0.1 <dbl [11]>      PRODUCT  
#  6      2 <dbl [11]>      0.1 <dbl [10 × 10]> DATAFRAME
#  7      3 <dbl [11]>      0.1 <dbl [1]>       SUM      
#  8      3 <dbl [11]>      0.1 <dbl [11]>      PRODUCT  
#  9      3 <dbl [11]>      0.1 <dbl [10 × 10]> DATAFRAME
# 10      1 <dbl [11]>      0.1 <dbl [1]>       SUM      
# # … with 44 more rows
```